# H5Screate_simple throws exception: dims rank is invalid

Tags: hdf5

I just started experimenting with HDF5 to see if I can use it in a new project.  I'm getting the following exception from a call to H5Screate_simple: dims rank is invalid.

I'm developing in Eclipse with Scala with Maven on OS X.  I'm using this [example](https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/releases/hdf5-1.10/hdf5-1.10.0-patch1/src/unpacked/java/examples/datasets/H5Ex_D_UnlimitedAdd.java) to build my test.  Here is the failing snippet:

```
def failTest() {
    val rank: Int = 2
    val dimSizes = Array[Long](1, 1)
    val maxDimSizes = Array[Long](1, 1)

    val dataSpaceID = H5.H5Screate_simple(rank, dimSizes, maxDimSizes)
}
```

Searching for the error message I found the code that throws the exception [here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/19907469/), see line 81.  This indicates the length of the dimSizes array does not match the value of rank, but in the snippet above the both are obviously 2.  I wondered if this could be some problem with the Array object in Scala (though I've never had problem passing arrays to java functions before).  So I wrote a test snippet in Java ...

```
public static void failTest() throws Exception {
    int rank = 2;
    long[] dims = { 1, 1 };
    long[] mdims = { 1, 1 };

    long dataSpaceID = H5.H5Screate_simple(rank, dims, mdims);

}
```

I get the same exception.  It all seems pretty straight forward, but I can't see any problem.  Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to an out of data package.  I setup my pom.xml to fetch the package from maven central, but the latest version posted there is 2.6.1 from 2010.  The latest version is 3.2.1.  For some reason they are not maintaining it at maven central.  I downloaded the latest from [here](https://support.hdfgroup.org/products/java/release/download.html).

I manually installed the jar in my maven repository with:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=jarhdf5-3.2.1.jar -DgroupId=org.hdfgroup -DartifactId=hdf-java -Dversion=3.2.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Then updated my pom.xml with

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hdfgroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>hdf-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

The download from hdfgroup was described as an installer, but it didn't seem to actually install anything.  So I also had to install the native library manually with:

```
ln -sf /<path_to_package>/HDFJAVA/3.2.1/lib/libjhdf.3.2.1.dylib /usr/local/lib/libjhdf.3.2.1.dylib
ln -sf /<path_to_package>/HDFJAVA/3.2.1/lib/libjhdf.3.2.1.dylib /usr/local/lib/libjhdf5.dylib
```